# Laravel time validation (hours:seconds)

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to validate a valid 24 hour time.

Request dump,

```
#parameters: array:6 [▼
    "_token" => "mP2b6fmvlQG6SMgMwz9VI9kZEXtjXqp7hXUjdWdZ"
    "email" => null
    "ageLimit" => null
    "timeFrom" => "0:00"
    "timeTo" => "0:00"
    "alowed_days" => array:7 [▶]
]
```

**Controller validation**

```
$validation = $request = $request->validate([
    'email' => 'email|required',
    'ageLimit' => 'required|numeric',
    'timeFrom' => 'date_format:H:i',
    'timeTo' => 'date_format:H:i',
)];
```

This is failing for some reason? I'm getting "The time from does not match the format H:i."

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Which part of the validation is failing. Looks to me like email and ageLimit will not validate either

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

> **G** 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros 0 through 23
>   ...
>   **H** 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23

The hour values in `0:00` don't have leading zeroes, so `H` isn't going to match. `date_format:G:i` should work.

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> H 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros
>
> i Minutes with leading zeros
>
> G 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros

Meaning that you should change `"timeFrom" => "0:00"` to `"timeFrom" => "00:00"` or use `G` instead of `H`.